# MySQL max_execution_time not working

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2019, mysql8

We have a general problem with MySQL 8 running on Windows 2019.
We see queries running forever and the CPU is 100%, the system becomes unresponsive.

While we know this needs a better investigation to be solved, and we're looking for a database expert to help us, for now, we are trying to solve this by having:

max_execution_time=30000

But this is not respected. Queries run for several minutes.

Why is this happening?

Thanks
Alex

[image: queries]

Comment: btw if you are a database expert and want to work with us please contact me at alex [at] ndros [dot] com

Comment: Please check your email - including spam.

Comment: Show us a slow query, including `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT...`